# Assert.AreEqual<> doesn’t call my operator== overloaded function nor my Equal member function?

Tags: generics, operator-overloading, assert

I have overloaded several compare operators like operator== in my class CXmlAttr. Then I wrote generic functions where I used these operators and was shocked that this didn’t work in C# or not in every case. Then I recoded some generic functions to explicit functions which work with the CXmlAttr type as argument. Additional I decided to use extensive unit test functions to check the behavior in several situations. And there was the next problem.
I wanted to debug these unit test and recognized that Assert.AreEqual<> didn’t call my overloaded== operators nor my Equal functions.  I set breakpoints in the appropriate functions but the debugger didn’t stop the execution. Then I tried to step into in the code, but this didn’t work too even I have configured to debug .NET code.

> **Question:** So does anybody know how Assert.AreEqual<> works and why my breakpoint didn’t work?

Assert.IsTrue(…==…) works fine.
I’m very unsure about how and if Assert.AreEqual<> works and if I can trust the results

```
public static void CompareCXmlAttr(LibKat.CXmlAttr left_attr, LibKat.CXmlAttr right_attr, EOper oper)
   {
       //  just for debugging
       System.Type gen_type = typeof(LibKat.CXmlAttr);
       string s_gen_name = gen_type.FullName;
       dynamic left = left_attr;
       dynamic right = right_attr;

       switch (oper)
       {
           case EOper.equal:
               //  operator== left == right -> true
               //debugger doesn't stop and no exception
               Assert.AreEqual<LibKat.CXmlAttr>(left, right, "typeof(T) == {0}, operator== (left == right) == false - but should be true", s_gen_name);
               //debugger stops in operator== function
               Assert.IsTrue((left == right), "typeof(T) == {0}, operator== (left == right) == false - but should be true", s_gen_name);
               //debugger doesn't stop and no exception
               Assert.AreEqual<LibKat.CXmlAttr>(left_attr, right_attr, "typeof(T) == {0}, operator== (left_attr == right_attr) == false - but should be true", s_gen_name);
               ////debugger stops in operator== function
               Assert.IsTrue((left_attr == right_attr), "typeof(T) == {0}, operator== (left_attr == right_attr) == false - but should be true", s_gen_name);

               break;
           case EOper.not_equal:
               //  operator!= left != right -> true


               break;
           case EOper.less:
           //result = (left < right ? true : false);
           case EOper.less_equal:
           //result = (left <= right ? true : false);
           case EOper.greater:
           //result = (left > right ? true : false);
           case EOper.greater_equal:
           //result = (left >= right ? true : false);
           default:
               System.Type type_oper = oper.GetType();
               string s_type_name = type_oper.FullName;
               string s_message = string.Format("typeof(T) == {0}, wrong (operator == {1}.{2}), only operator EOper.equal, EOper.not_equal allowed", s_gen_name, s_type_name, oper);
               string s_identifier_name = IdentifierAsStringGetFromLinqExpression<EOper>(() => oper); //prepare code for expression to parse and get the identifier name as string
               string s_ident_name = IdentifierAsStringGetFromTypeProperty(new { oper }); //generic call to get type info and name of identifier inside the initializer list - the faster version
               throw new System.ArgumentException(s_message, s_ident_name);
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation but I can't be sure it's the same cause because your code appears incomplete (I don't find `LibKat.CXmlAttr` anywhere on the internet other than in this question). However, you might look at whether or not you (or `LibKat`) implemented `operator ==` but did not override `Object.Equals`.  This would cause similar behavior and should generate a tell-tale [CS0660 compiler warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0660).